# SceneKit : how to change the color of an object

Tags: swift, macos, scenekit

I read the docs from Apple and they say that the solution is inside UIKit; unfortunately, I'm not writing code for IOs but MacOS so no UIKit.

What is the correct object which allows me to change the color?

```
sphereGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = ??
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
sphereGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = NSColor(calibratedRed: 0.3, green: 0.5, blue: 0.4, alpha: 1 )
```

NSColor is the object to use to get the job done.

Comment: Or you can also use UIColor
`sphereGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor(red: 0.3, green: 0.5, blue: 0.4, alpha: 1 )`